# Gulp can't find ruby and compass in system path

Tags: javascript, ruby, macos, gulp, compass

I installed gulp and everything seems fine except for this error when running the gulp command. I get
 Error: You need to have Ruby and Compass installed and in your system PATH for this task to work.
when issuing the command. I am on mac osx 10.11 if that helps. My gulp was installed in /Users/Desktop/responsive/ .

Server started http://localhost:8080
[11:10:21] LiveReload started on port 35729
[11:10:21] { [Error: You need to have Ruby and Compass installed and in your system PATH for this task to work.]
  message: 'You need to have Ruby and Compass installed and in your system PATH for this task to work.',
  showStack: false,
  showProperties: true,
  plugin: 'gulp-compass',
  __safety: { toString: [Function: bound ] } }
Any ideas to what the issue is. All help appreciated.

Comment: you need to install [ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/) on your system, after this install gem-compass using `gem install compass`, Refer this link [Installing Ruby](http://compass-style.org/install/)

Answer (score 6):

Ruby comes preinstalled on Mac machines so you shouldn't need to install it. If you have not installed the compass gem you'll need to do so. To check that you have these...

**Check ruby** with `$ ruby -v`
**Check compass** with `$ compass version`

For both make sure you get a error free response that lists a version. If you don't have either or them installed, install them (ruby first if you don't have them both)...

**Install ruby**
There are a lot of ways to do this. I recommend using homebrew. Once you have it it is super useful for installing a lot of things. You'll need to google how to install it if you don't have it. There are many other ways to install ruby, see the official [docs](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/installation/#homebrew). Using homebrew...

`$ brew install ruby`

**install compass**
Now that you have ruby (or if you already did) you can easily install compass...

`$ gem install compass`

This command may need to be run using `sudo`. You'll know if you get a permissions error. After installing restart terminal and check again, then try gulp.